# Git latest commit replaced by previous commit changes

Tags: git

I am having this weird problem with Git.

**Current condition:**

I have a file `xyzzy.c` which has a change log of following commits.

```
axdgtye...
jiid783...
90dy73h...
```

When I pull latest from remote master branch, I get the version of `xyzzy.c` which was last changes in the commit `axdgtye...`

Everything sounds good so far, but it is not true, until the following I say.

When I see the list of commits in the same file in the server, from web browser (using bitbucket) I see the commit on the master branch (arranging commits from latest to previous):

```
hjeuu23...
axdgtye...
jiid783...
90dy73h...
```

**Expected Changes:**

I have made last changes in the file `xyzzy.c` which went to master with commit `hjeuu23...`. And hence I should expect that any latest revision from master would have `hjeuu23...` commit as latest one. Which means if I git log the change list, I should see following:

```
hjeuu23...
axdgtye...
jiid783...
90dy73h...
```

**Suspecting:**

I think what could cause this problem is that after I made my changes in `xyzzy.c` someone else working on a different branch didn't get the latest revision from master, and made changes in a different file and forcefully committed it to master that my changes in `hjeuu23...` got reverted to `axdgtye...` in the master branch.

As I mentioned before, here `git log` is only showing

```
 axdgtye...
 jiid783...
 90dy73h...
```

Assuming that my hypothesis is true, is there a way to find out when was this file reverted from `hjeuu23...` to `axdgtye...`?

Comment: are you trying to ***blame*** someone for the file getting messed up? *wink wink* (yes you can with the `git blame` command)

Comment: @bolov Thanks for your comments. I have spent sometime understanding the git blame command, since i haven't used it before, and used it in multiple ways to analyze the results. Seems like this is not what I'm looking for. The history of the entire file got rewritten in master.